# C++ wxsocket TCP server send unsigned char array but python client get 4 more bytes in

Tags: python, c++, sockets

Hi I sent an wxImage using C++ TCP socket to python TCP clientlike this:

C++ TCP Server is like this:

```
//this part is the TCP server m_sock send the unsigned char* ImageData
std::stringstream imageStream1;
imageStream1 << ImageData;
m_sock->Write(imageStream1.str().c_str(), imageStream1.str().length());

//Then I send a simple string "hello"
std::stringstream dataStream2;
dataStream2 <<  "hello";
m_sock->Write(dataStream2.str().c_str(), dataStream2.str().length());
dataStream2.clear();
```

So I receive the two message in python

```
// This is used to receive the image data with the exact same bytes of the ImageData
packet = socket.recv(ImageDataSize)
myWxImage.SetData(packet)

// This is used to receive the second "hello" message
packet = socket.recv(1000)
```

I can received the image successfully. But when I print the message, it shows "****hello" but not "hello". There is an additional 4 bytes string in front of it. the four "*" is something python can not print out. what is it? Can I get rid of it?

Answer (score 0):

```
std::stringstream imageStream1;
imageStream1 << ImageData;
m_sock->Write(imageStream1.str().c_str(), imageStream1.str().length());
```

looks like a bad idea. I don't know the type of ImageData, but converting it to a `std::stringstream` is definitely not the best way to go about this. If `ImageData` just contains a reference to a raw image buffer, use that. Images are not strings, and obviously, things will go wrong if you get the `c_str()` from something that might contain `\x00` in its data (because that's what normally terminates C strings).

Then:

```
//Then I send a simple string "hello"
std::stringstream dataStream2;
dataStream2 <<  "hello";
m_sock->Write(dataStream2.str().c_str(), dataStream2.str().length());
dataStream2.clear();
```

Um, do you understand what you're writing here? You take a perfectly valid C string , `"hello"`, you push it onto a stringstream, just to get a C string out again?

To be honest: I think you're copy&pasting code from an example without understanding it. You should go back and understand every single line before usage.

Comment: Just because the example is simple does not necessarily mean the poster does not know what they are doing. Afterall, we are encouraged to create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

#### How to remove the "****"

In general to just remove characters from a python string you can do this:

```
cleaned_data = str(packet).replace("*", "")
```

Please remember that when you receive data in `packet` that you are receiving bytes and not a string, so if you try to print directly python has do an implicit conversion for you. In this case, I think it would be better to do an explicit conversion and remove the beginning.

However, it doesn't solve the problem of why you are getting the characters in the first place. These 4 "*" could potentially stem from an encoding issue.

#### Trouble Shooting

It would be worth it to connect the python program to debugger (maybe PyCharm) so that you could see the actual values that are before "Hello", this would give you an idea of where to look so that you do not have to deal with conversions from bytes to unicode or whatever locale your console is in.

If you could get that and post that info it might help others to help you.